# Extracting embedded XML File from PDF A/3 using abcpdf in C# - ZUGFeRD

Tags: c#, xml, abcpdf, pdfa, zugferd

I'm currently working with the new German ZUGFeRD files. These are PDF A/3 files who have an embedded XML file in them which contains data.

I want to extract this XML file from the PDF A/3 using abcpdf 8.1 with C#.

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks a lot  and regards,

Comment: I'd get a library which deals with PDF files, then load the attached XML with XDocument.

Comment: My Library dealing with PDF files is abcpdf in Version 8.1. My question is how to extract/read the xml which is inside the pdf with this library(abcpdf). Thanks anyway !:)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200344/how-to-extract-embedded-files-and-attachment-from-pdf-using-pdfsharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know abcpdf but I guess that the pdf libs offer similar access to the pdfs content.

First take a look at [Das-ZUGFeRD-Format_1p0.pdf](http://konik.io/ZUGFeRD-Spezifikation/Das-ZUGFeRD-Format_1p0.pdf). Especially page 112. The images shows the object tree you have to traverse in order to find the xml stream.

With this tree you have the names, the types and the direction. Now you can traverse the pdf object tree to get to the XML content that you are looking for.

The steps based on the diagram.

1. Read your PDF
2. Get the catalog inside your PDF
3. Get the Array with name `AF` from Catalog
4. Get first element from `AF` array (should be `file spec`)
5. From `file spec` get the dictionary named `EF`
6. Get the stream content of `EF`

This are the steps you need to perform in order to get to the content.

To display the structure of a pdf and browse the tree I would recommend to use a tool like [iText RUPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty much the way to go !

What did i do with abcpdf:

-Get the Objectsoup Array from the Doc (Pretty much an array of all Objects in the Doc)
-as ZUGFeRD allows only one embedded file inside the PDF, i just searched this objectsoup-array for the one of the type StreamObject that contains /EmbeddedFile
-Decompress the Stream of that object, get the byte[] of the stream and write it into an xml file

Comment: @user3296596 *ZUGFeRD allows only one embedded file inside the PDF* - That's wrong: *only one invoice but any number of other attachments,* "nur die Einbindung eines einzigen Rechnungsdatendokuments ... Einbettung weiterer Dokumente und Dateien, die keine Rechnungsdaten enthalten, ist davon nicht betroffen". Furthermore this is subject to change, "In künftigen Versionen des ZUGFeRD Standards kann diese Beschränkung aufgehoben werden", cf. the PDF-Implementierungsguide-ZUGFeRD.pdf from the info package.

Comment: @Vadimo I think it is not a good idea to remove the reference to http://www.ferd-net.de completely and only link to a copy of the specification on the site of an implementation of ZUGFeRD, http://konik.io; admittedly, though, wikipedia does reference those copies, too.

Answer (score -2):

What did i do with abcpdf:

- Get the Objectsoup Array from the Doc (Pretty much an array of all Objects in the Doc)
- as ZUGFeRD allows only one embedded file inside the PDF, i just searched this objectsoup-array for the one of the type StreamObject that contains /EmbeddedFile
- Decompress the Stream of that object, get the byte[] of the stream and write it into an xml file

Comment: *ZUGFeRD allows only one embedded file inside the PDF* - That's wrong: **only one invoice but any number of other attachments**, "nur die Einbindung eines einzigen Rechnungsdatendokuments ... Einbettung weiterer Dokumente und Dateien, die keine Rechnungsdaten enthalten, ist davon nicht betroffen". Furthermore this is subject to change, "In künftigen Versionen des ZUGFeRD Standards kann diese Beschränkung aufgehoben werden", cf. the PDF-Implementierungsguide-ZUGFeRD.pdf from the info package.