# How to extract embedded files and attachment from PDF using PdfSharp?

Tags: pdf, extract, attachment, pdfsharp

Is it possible to extract embedded files and attachment from PDF using PdfSharp? if yes how can we achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seems like PDFSharp is not supporting [attachments](http://forum.pdfsharp.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=571) directly but you may try to implement attachments extraction support: you need to look for */FS* streams inside PDF document described in [PDF Reference 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) in Section 3.10.3 and in note 94 in Appendix H.

Answer (score -1):

you may try Apose.pdf, it works perfect for extract embedded files and attachment from PDF.
Try the following.

```
            Document pdfDocument = new Document(@"C:\tmp\AddAttachment_out.pdf");

            // Get embedded files collection
            EmbeddedFileCollection embeddedFiles = pdfDocument.EmbeddedFiles;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Total files : {0}", embeddedFiles.Count);

            int count = 1;

            // Loop through the collection to get all the attachments
            foreach (FileSpecification fileSpecification in embeddedFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", fileSpecification.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}",
                fileSpecification.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Mime Type: {0}", fileSpecification.MIMEType);

                // Check if parameter object contains the parameters
                /*if (fileSpecification.Params != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CheckSum: {0}",
                    fileSpecification.Params.CheckSum);
                    Console.WriteLine("Creation Date: {0}",
                    fileSpecification.Params.CreationDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("Modification Date: {0}",
                    fileSpecification.Params.ModDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", fileSpecification.Params.Size);
                }*/
            
                // Get the attachment and write to file or stream
                byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileSpecification.Contents.Length];
                fileSpecification.Contents.Read(fileContent, 0,
                fileContent.Length);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Tmp\\" + count + "_out" + ".pdf",
                FileMode.Create);
                fileStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
                count += 1;

                
            }
```